# How to create a custom environment in Grails?

Tags: grails, groovy

[grails.util.Environment](http://grails.org/doc/latest/api/grails/util/Environment.html), defines a number of preconfigured environments

- DEVELOPMENT
- PRODUCTION
- TEST
- CUSTOM

When running a Grails command, the environment to use can be specified using a `-Denv` flag, e.g. `grails run-app -Denv=test`. You can also specify a block of code that is specific to a certain environment using closures such as:

```
environments {
    production {
        grails.serverURL = "http://www.changeme.com"
    }
    development {
        grails.serverURL = "http://localhost:8080/${appName}"
    }
    test {
        grails.serverURL = "http://localhost:8080/${appName}"
    }
}
```

These environment-specific closures can be used in `Bootstrap.groovy` and `Config.groovy`, are there other places?

Also, is it possible for me to define my own environment, e.g. `PRE_PRODUCTION`, such that it will work with the closures above and the `-Denv` flag?

Finally, can the `CUSTOM` environment be used with the `-Denv` flag?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> These environment-specific closures
>   can be used in Bootstrap.groovy and
>   Config.groovy, are there other places?

I don't think so...  For other places, you would need to use the [Generic Per Environment Execution](http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/conf.html#environments) block

```
Environment.executeForCurrentEnvironment {
    production {
        // do something in production
    }
    development {
        // do something only in development
    }
    pre_production {
        // do something for your custom environment
    }
}
```

> Also, is it possible for me to define
>   my own environment, e.g.
>   PRE_PRODUCTION, such that it will work
>   with the closures above and the -Denv
>   flag?

Yeah, you should be able to just declare `-Dgrails.env=pre_production` and include the `pre_production` block in Bootstrap.groovy or Config.groovy (or a custom `grails.util.Environment` block as above)

**edit**

As you can see in the Grails [source for Environment](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-bootstrap/src/main/groovy/grails/util/Environment.java#L91), this sort of custom environment will enumerate to Environment.CUSTOM, and then in the `Environment.executeForCurrentEnvironment` block, it will [check against CUSTOM, and the name of the custom environment](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-bootstrap/src/main/groovy/grails/util/Environment.java#L299)

Comment: Thanks, any idea if `PRE_PRODUCTION` would get added to the `grails.utils.Environment` enum? This seems unlikely, because I don't think constants can be added to an enum at runtime.

Comment: Updated my answer to cover this...no, it doesn't add to the Enum, you just get flagged as `Environment.CUSTOM` with a `String` for the name of your custom environment

Comment: Thanks for the update. It seems like there's no need to configure the list of custom environments anywhere, you can just go ahead and use them (as shown above)?

Comment: Yeah...  Obviously spelling mistakes on the command line when specifying the `-Denv` parameter are going to haunt you if you make any ;-)

Answer (score 4):

If you create a custom environment, you can use it anywhere that the `environments {}` block is used. For example, in addition to `Bootstrap.groovy` and `Config.groovy`, you can also use it in `DataSource.groovy` and even other Config files like `Searchable.groovy`.

Also, I believe

`Environment.currentEnvironment.name` will return `'pre_production'` in your case.

Answer (score 1):

`-Dgrails.env=pre_production`

More here in the [Grails documentation for configuration environments](https://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/conf.html#environments)

Comment: This is the only answer that has the correct command line option for selecting the environment.