# define custom grails environment

Tags: grails, groovy

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323705/grails-environments), I thought I could define something like this in (for example) `resources.groovy`

```
def currentEnv = Environment.current
if (currentEnv == Environment.CUSTOM && currentEnv.name == 'mock') {
    println 'Do some stuff for the mock env'
}
```

The code in the if-statement should be executed when I run (for example) `grails run-app -Denv=mock` but it isn't, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9):

You must use the method `Environment.executeForCurrentEnvironment()`, like this:

```
import grails.util.Environment

     grails.util.Environment.executeForCurrentEnvironment {
         development {
             println 'Running in DEV mode.'
         }
         production {
             println 'Running in production mode.'
         }
         mock {
             println 'Running in custom "mock" mode.'
         }
     }
```

and call grails this way: `grails -Dgrails.env=mock run-app`

Take a look at [this blogpost](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2010/05/grails-goodness-execute-code-for.html), from mrhaki.

Comment: It didn't work @Dónal's way because he was calling grails wrong. His logic was fine but he needed to use -Dgrails.env instead of -Denv

Comment: I am using grails 2.3.2 and this solution with Environment.executeForCurrentEnvironment and a custom enviroment, does not work for me. It does not matter with ENV I set grails(dev or prod), it always print the 'Running in custom "mock" mode.' and then print the current enviroment I set (dev or prod), any ideas why?

Answer (score 1):

Note that this may be a problem if you have multiple custom environments defined. I am using Grails 2.4.4. If I have a mytest and myqa environment defined, BOTH will be executed by Grails because both are Environment.CUSTOM, meaning some bean definitions are overwritten or misconfigured!

```
 grails.util.Environment.executeForCurrentEnvironment {
     development {
         println 'Running in DEV mode.'
     }
     mytest {
         println 'This will be evaluated because it is CUSTOM'
     }
     myqa {
         println 'This will ALSO be evaluated because it is CUSTOM. Yikes!'
     }
 }
```

I don't know if that's a bug or by design. Anyway, here is what I do and this seems to work properly:

```
 switch(Environment.current.name) {
     case 'development':
         println 'Running in DEV mode.'
         break

     case 'mytest':
         println 'Running in mytest mode'
         break

     case 'myqa':
         println 'Running in myqa mode'
         break
 }
```