# Environment.executeForCurrentEnvironment bugs for custom ENV in grails 2.3.2?

Tags: spring, grails, groovy

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5354757/define-custom-grails-environment) and its responses, I decided to use `Environment.executeForCurrentEnvironment` to inject beans depending on the environment. This is my code:

```
Environment.executeForCurrentEnvironment {
    development {
        // In development we use DevelopmentEmailer as implementation of emailer.
        springConfig.addAlias 'emailer', 'developmentEmailer'
    }
    devReport {
        // In custom Env we use DevelopmentEmailer as implementation of emailer.
        springConfig.addAlias 'emailer', 'developmentEmailer'
    }
    production {
        springConfig.addAlias 'emailer', 'emailer'
    }

}
```

> devReport is my Custom enviroment.

But which is my surprise when I debug with env=PROD and I found this:

[image: debuger in prod env]

It does not matter which -Dgrails.env I use to set the enviroment to run the app. It always set the alias for my custom env first (later, in the next step is set for prod aswell and correct the wrong alias). But the issue is still here.

**Solution**

The solution is simple, just use this:

```
switch(Environment.current.name) {
    case 'development':
        springConfig.addAlias 'emailer', 'developmentEmailer'
        break

    case 'devReport':
        springConfig.addAlias 'emailer', 'developmentEmailer'
        break

    case 'production':
        springConfig.addAlias 'emailer', 'emailer'
        break
}
```

But I am still wondering why, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

For those that may still care about this, you can workaround this issue by qualifying your custom profile with `delegate.` - for example:

```
Environment.executeForCurrentEnvironment {
    development {
        // In development we use DevelopmentEmailer as implementation of emailer.
        springConfig.addAlias 'emailer', 'developmentEmailer'
    }
    delegate.devReport {
        // In custom Env we use DevelopmentEmailer as implementation of emailer.
        springConfig.addAlias 'emailer', 'developmentEmailer'
    }
    production {
        springConfig.addAlias 'emailer', 'emailer'
    }

}
```