# Why Grails unit, integration and functional test phases do not have their own environment?

Tags: grails

- Unit test don't need a database.
- Integration and functional tests can have different fixtures and bootstrap data.
- It would be also better to split functional tests on application itself and Selenium testing robot.

So, is there any reason to keep all tests phases in one environment?

Answer (score 1):

I guess that's just a convention, since:

- The setup of the unit tests configure a memory database to let you use GORM methods.
- Your database will be initialized only when running integration tests.
- Functional tests are treated as extension and depending on your project they're not mandated (for example: plugin projects that does not rely on UI).

Nothing stops you to define [custom environments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323705/how-to-create-a-custom-environment-in-grails) and [run specific commands to them](http://www.grails.org/Environments). You can also create Spring Beans and configure database access according to your env, using the [Environment class](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.x/api/grails/util/Environment.html).

```
if(Environment.current == Environment.DEVELOPMENT) {
  ...
}
```