# How can i set a new custom environment for my grails application in productive servers?

Tags: grails, webserver, environment

I have a GRAILS Webserver application, which is up and running in a pool of production servers (environment "production"). I am trying to set a new ENVIRONMENT into those servers.

I already have my Config.groovy, where the new environment configuration is located. But, i don't know how to tell the production server to run into this!

Does that make any sense? Thanks!!

Comment: Here is how to configure your custom environment , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323705/how-to-create-a-custom-environment-in-grails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set it on compile time, so if you need `staging` environment, make war using:

```
grails -Dgrails.env=staging war
```

See http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/war.html

Comment: Thank you, i have been realized